# sum rows by 7 days interval starting from a specific date Oracle query

Tags: sql, database, datetime, oracle10g, sum

I have a table.

```
 SQL> desc weighment_tran;
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 SEASON_CD                       NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 IN_OUT_FLAG                     NOT NULL CHAR(1)
 IN_DATE                         NOT NULL DATE
 OUT_DATE                                 DATE
 SYSTEM_IN_DATE                  NOT NULL DATE
 SYSTEM_OUT_DATE                          DATE
 GROSS_WT                        NOT NULL NUMBER(10,3)
 TARE_WT                         NOT NULL NUMBER(10,3)
 GROSS_NET_TARE_WT               NOT NULL NUMBER(10,3)
 LESS_DEDUCTION_WT               NOT NULL NUMBER(10,3)
 GROSS_NET_DEDUCTION_WT          NOT NULL NUMBER(10,3)
 LESS_BINDING_WT                 NOT NULL NUMBER(10,3)
 NET_WT                          NOT NULL NUMBER(10,3)
 VEHICLE_NO                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 PAYMENT_FLAG                    NOT NULL CHAR(1)
 VEHICLE_TYPE                    NOT NULL CHAR(1)
 CROP_TYPE_CD                    NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 ADD_DATE                        NOT NULL DATE
```

What I want is

```
               Season_CD1           |            Season_CD2           |            Total
      ------------------------------|---------------------------------|-------------------------------
      Crop_type_CD1  | Crop_type_CD2|  Crop_type_CD1  | Crop_type_CD2 |Crop_type_CD1  | Crop_type_CD2
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1st Week
2nd Week
3rd Week
```

and I tried this but no luck

```
select trunc(min(out_date),'dd-mm-yy') + 
(trunc(to_char(min(out_date),'dd')/7)*7)/24/60, sum(net_wt)
from agri.weighment_tran where weighment_tran.season_cd=9
group by  trunc(min(out_date),'dd-mm-yy') + 
(trunc(to_char(min(out_date),'dd')/7)*7)/24/60, sum(net_wt)
```

I want sum of 'net_wt' on weekly basis and & starting day for week start should be min(out_date)

Comment: Can you upload a SQLFiddle of sample data?

Comment: @mmmmmpie I am getting lot of errors while creating SQLFIDDLE

Comment: It's going to be very hard without some data.